# Change the items of ComboBox from one form to other form with same database

Tags: c#, windows, forms, combobox

I have some question.

I build Menu as use of tabcontrol and tab with use of forms

I have first form:

[image]

Have there some actions - update,delete...

---

and there is other form

[image]

I tried at second form after first form make the differents actions update the combobox where written code of movie immediately when I pass to second tab/form, but it not make anything

Sorry for my bad English and thanks,

Ariel

Answer (score 0):

How are you trying to update the combobox? Check out this question - [ComboBox: Adding Text and Value to an Item (no Binding Source)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3063320/combobox-adding-text-and-value-to-an-item-no-binding-source)
It looks like you first need to override the combobox so you can modify it. Then you need something like this to do it from `Form2` (pseudo code);

```
   Form2_EventHandeler()
   {
          Form1.ComboBox.Add(Form2.TextBoxWithNewInput.Text);
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can write new public function in form 2

for exmple in form2

```
public void updateForm()
{
      // readCombo box data from db

}
```

and call from form 1 after update oder delete
for exmple in delete_click or update_click event

Comment: what you mean call - the combobox?

Comment: I have other form that has connection to first form, but two other combobox, for eaxmaple if i want do delete some item on combobox i want to see the change at second form without close the wf to see that

Comment: ok i often write a function in form 2 this form call functionality for upgrade combobox and call this function from form 1

Comment: i think i should use the tabs as they are becasue i dont understand what to do