# What is the best way to convert this string into number of minutes?

Tags: c#, string, winforms, parsing, combobox

I have a combobox in winforms that has the following items:

```
 15 min
 30 min
 1 hr
 1 hr 30 min
 2 hr
 2 hr 30 min
etc . .
```

Here is the screenshot of the winforms combobox Collection Items editor

[image]

and i need to parse that string and return an integer which represents the number of minutes.  I wanted to see the most elegant way of doing that (right now i am splitting by space and then counting array length and it feels a bit wrong.

So parsing

```
2h 30 mins
```

would return 150

Comment: Why don't you store the number of minutes along each dropdown entry?

Comment: what do you mean by number of minutes?are you counting or adding..be clear with your question...

Comment: Which technology? (asp.net, forms, wpf etc) or doesn't it matter?

Comment: When using a dropdownlist one thing is the text, and something else is the value. Have the value be the minutes. Then get the value of the Selected item.

Comment: @Xeano - its winforms but i don't see why that matters

Comment: @Dzyann - I added a screenshot, i don't see a place to put values on a combobox

Comment: @Anirudh - basically adding 60 * hours + mins and returning a number

Comment: @leora I saw the question when you said it was a dropdown :)

Comment: @leora check out this solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3063320/combobox-adding-text-and-value-to-an-item-no-binding-source You could have your minutes in the values and then show the string in whatever way you want.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you said this is a *combobox*, then you will have to parse the value.  Your user might enter a value of their own as well.

```
var formats = new[] {"h' hr'", "m' min'", "h' hr 'm' min'"};

TimeSpan ts;
if (!TimeSpan.TryParseExact(value, formats, null, out ts))
{
    // raise a validation message to your user.
}

// you said you wanted an integer number of minutes.
var minutes = (int) ts.TotalMinutes;
```

You can pass any of the strings you showed in your example as the `value`.

**However**, be aware that due to how `TimeSpan` works, you cannot parse more than 23 hours or more than 59 minutes with this approach.  Passing "24 hr" or "60 min" or any combination of such will fail.

Comment: I added the screenshot, where would you put the values?

Comment: That's not a dropdown, that's a combo box.  So yes, you will need to parse.

Comment: I updated to show using `TryParseExact` instead, which is more useful in the scenario you described.

Comment: One more edit.  Since this is UI, it's probably better to use the current culture (null) instead of the invariant one.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use a `Dictionary` for this, so there's no parsing at all involved. (It works well when there are fixed choices.) I'm more familiar with Delphi's UI controls than .NETs, so there might be a better way to populate the `ComboBox` than what I'm doing here, but I'm sure someone will let me know if there is and I can fix it.

(Code is Oxygene, but it should be easily translatable to C# or VB.Net.)

```
method MainForm.MainForm_Load(sender: System.Object; e: System.EventArgs);
var
  KC: Dictionary<String, Int32>.KeyCollection;
begin
  aItems := new Dictionary<String, Int32>;
  aItems.Add('15 min', 15);
  aItems.Add('30 min', 30);
  aItems.Add('1 hr', 60);
  aItems.Add('1 hr 30 min', 90);
  aItems.Add('2 hr', 120);
  aItems.Add('2 hr 30 min', 150);
  KC := aItems.Keys;
  for s in KC do
    comboBox2.Items.Add(s);
  comboBox2.DropDownStyle := ComboBoxStyle.DropDownList;
end;

method MainForm.comboBox2_SelectedIndexChanged(sender: System.Object; e: System.EventArgs);
begin
  // Safe since style is DropDownList. 
  label1.Text := aItems[comboBox2.SelectedItem.ToString].ToString(); 
end;
```

Answer (score -1):

This should work:

```
   static int GetAllNumbersFromString(string timeString)
   {
    int min = 0;

    MatchCollection mc=Regex.Matches(timeString, @"\d+");

    if(timeString.Contains("hr") && mc.Count = 1)
    {

          min = mc[0] * 60;

    }
    else
    {

        if(mc.Count > 1)
        {
            min = mc[0] * 60 + mc[1];
        }
        else
        {
            min = mc[0];
        }
    }

    return min;
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work . . when you parse "1 hr" it return 1 (not 60)