# How can I make a ComboBox auto post back in WinForms application?

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox

I have a Windows Forms application for employees and when I select the employee name 
from a ComboBox, textboxes should be filled with the data of the selected employee. I remember something like the auto postback property but I can't find it in Visual Studio.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There is no such thing called AutoPostback in winforms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using WinForms, there's no such thing as `AutoPostBack`, that is for ASP.NET. In your case use the `SelectedIndexChanged`-event. In this event you can get the selected item and based on this item, get the corresponding data of the employee and fill the textboxes.

More info:

- [MSDN: ComboBox.SelectedIndexChanged Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.selectedindexchanged%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Pseudo-code:

```
private void YourComboBox_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string item = (string)YourComboBox.SelectedItem;
    //Fetch data (dummy method)
    Employee emp = GetDataByName(item);
    //Write to TextBox
    SomeTextBox.Text = emp.Function;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Winforms provides the following events:

> SelectedIndexChanged  Occurs when the SelectedIndex property has
>   changed. SelectedValueChanged    Occurs when the SelectedValue
>   property changes.

You can read more about them here: [MSDN Combobox.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You should use the SelectedIndexChanged event of the Combobox. Normally you'll get it when you double click to the ComboBox on your form.

In order to store a text with a value (suppose ID) and add it to the Combobox, follow this answer:

> https://stackoverflow.com/a/11745699/870865

For an Example:

```
// On load event, add the items to the ComboBox following the above link I have posted...

private void cmbEmployees_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
      int EmployeeID = ((KeyValuePair<string, string>)cmbEmployees.SelectedItem).Value;
      var Employee = SomeClass.getEmployeeByID(EmployeeID); // Write a class or a method to get Employee as an object... 
      txtName.Text = Employee.Name;
      txtEmail.Text = Empolyee.Email;
}
```

Hope this gives you an idea!