# c# ComboBox, save item with value and text

Tags: c#, combobox

I am trying to add an object ITEM with TEXT and VALUE to a ComboBox so I can read it later

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    ComboboxItem item;
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        comboBox1.Items.Add(new ComboboxItem("Dormir", 12).Text);
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ComboboxItem c = (ComboboxItem)comboBox1.SelectedItem;
        label1.Text = c.Text;
        label2.Text = c.Value.ToString();
    }
}
```

The problem is, I cant add the full Item because isn't a string...and give an exception at beginning of click event

---

Extra information:
This ComboboxItem, its a class that I created with 2 parameters, string, and int

```
public class ComboboxItem
{
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public object Value { get; set; }

    public ComboboxItem(string texto, double valor)
    {
        this.Text = texto;
        this.Value = valor;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could (should) set the displaymember and valuemember in another place, but...

```
public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        comboBox1.DisplayMember="Text";
        comboBox1.ValueMember ="Value";
        comboBox1.Items.Add(new ComboboxItem("Dormir", 12));
    }
```

Comment: thanks!, thats what i realy wanted!, maybe my english wasnt good.. i wanted to add a item but show text ;)

Answer (score 0):

you dont need to add .Text at the end of ("text","value")

so add it as :

```
comboBox1.Items.Add(new ComboBoxItem("dormir","12"));
```

Comment: value doesn't come before the text, here : it's just the ctor of ComboBoxItem.

Comment: Like that, on my combobox will apear "WindowsFormsApplication1.ComboboxItem" instead "text".

Comment: I dont get your point @user3249619 the code that I provided should suffice

Comment: @user3249619 do you have something like `comboBox1.DisplayMember = "Text";
    comboBox1.ValueMember = "Value";`

Comment: @user3249619 you mean to say, you want to hide the value?

Comment: i want only to show TEXT, thats why i places ".text" in the end

Comment: the text and values are being added to the combobox, you should never put .text over there. :)

Answer (score 0):

You are on the right lines by creating your own ComboBoxItem class.

```
public class ComboboxItem
{
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public object Value { get; set; }

}
```

There are two ways to use this, (Constructor aside):
**Method 1:**

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ComboboxItem item = new ComboboxItem();
    item.Text = "Item text1";
    item.Value = 12;

    comboBox1.Items.Add(item);
}
```

**Method 2:**

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ComboboxItem item = new ComboboxItem 
    { 
         Text = "Item text1",
         Value = 12
    };

    comboBox1.Items.Add(item);
}
```

Have you tried adding it like this instead? Then when ever you get the Item out just cast it as a ComboboxItem :)

```
...
var selectedItem = comboBox1.SelectedItem as ComboboxItem;
var myValue = selectedItem.Value;
...
```

Alternative KeyValuePair:

```
comboBox1.Items.Add(new KeyValuePair("Item1", "Item1 Value"));
```

*Question based on returnign string value and other combobox answers..*
[ComboBox: Adding Text and Value to an Item (no Binding Source)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3063320/combobox-adding-text-and-value-to-an-item-no-binding-source)

Comment: if i do "comboBox1.Items.Add(item);", on my combobox it will not show "item text1" but instead shows ""WindowsFormsApplication1.ComboboxItem"

Comment: You could always just pass in a KeyValuePair?

Answer (score 0):

Create the ComboboxItem class and override the ToString method.
The ToString method will be called to visualize the item.   By default, ToString() returns the typename.

```
public class ComboboxItem
{
   public object Value{get;set;}
   public string Text {get;set;}

   public override string ToString(){ return Text; }
}
```

Then, you can do this:

```
var item = new CombobxItem { Value = 123, Text = "Some text" };
combobox1.Items.Add(item);
```

Comment: Could of just linked your answer to here?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3063320/combobox-adding-text-and-value-to-an-item-no-binding-source