# NullReferenceException while transferring the selected items from one ComboBox to another

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, combobox, nullreferenceexception

I am trying to transfer the selected items of one combo box to another using following code:

```
ComboBoxItem shift1Driver = new ComboBoxItem(); 
shift1Driver.Text = (comboBoxDriverShift1.SelectedItem as ComboBoxItem).Text;
shift1Driver.Value = (comboBoxDriverShift1.SelectedItem as ComboBoxItem).Value.ToString();
comboBoxAccountsDriverName.Items.Add(shift1Driver);
```

The ComboBoxItem class is user-defined and used to store combo box text and values together.

```
public class ComboBoxItem
   {
       public ComboBoxItem()
       {
           Text = "ComboBoxItem1";
           Value = "ComboBoxItem1";
       }
       public string Text { get; set; }
       public object Value { get; set; }

       public override string ToString()
       {
           return Text;
       }
   }
```

But the code is throwing `NullReferenceException` and I am unable to find a reason for it. The values are being fetched like this from ComboBox:
[image]
But not assigning them to `ComboBoxItem`'s object `shift1Driver`. Please help.

Comment: Obviously, `SelectedItem` is not `ComboBoxItem`. I can see first letters of its type on the screenshot: `System.Dat...`

Comment: then how should I solve this? It's actually working in my another application with same logic. This logic I took from here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3063320/combobox-adding-text-and-value-to-an-item-no-binding-source

Comment: Use the debugger to inspect what Type `comboBoxDriverShift.SelectedItem` is.

Comment: As a guess, you combobox is data-binded. In this case, its items have type of the `DataSource`'s items.

Comment: @rene its `DataRowView` type. How should I type cast it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you indicated in the comments that the type of your SelectedItem is [`DataRowView`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Data.DataRowView_properties%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) you have no cast available. Instead build your type `ComboBoxItem` manually like so:

```
var rowView = (DataRowView) comboBoxDriverShift1.SelectedItem;  // cast 
ComboBoxItem shift1Driver = new ComboBoxItem {
     Text = rowView[1].ToString(),
     Value = rowView[0]
};
comboBoxAccountsDriverName.Items.Add(shift1Driver);
```

Or a little bit more condensed:

```
comboBoxAccountsDriverName.Items.Add(new ComboBoxItem {
     Text = ((DataRowView) comboBoxDriverShift1.SelectedItem)[1].ToString(),
     Value = ((DataRowView) comboBoxDriverShift1.SelectedItem)[0]
});
```

Comment: Thanks, I modified my code according to your answer like this `ComboBoxItem shift1Driver = new ComboBoxItem() { Text = ((DataRowView)comboBoxDriverShift1.SelectedItem).Row.ItemArray[1].ToString(), Value = (((DataRowView)comboBoxDriverShift1.SelectedItem).Row.ItemArray[0]) };` and its working.