# How to add value dynamically in a combo box in windows application

Tags: c#

I am having a two combo box .I want to add the values which are not selected in the 1st combo box to the 2nd combo box dynamically .

Comment: so what's the problem? (hint, use a couple of temp lists)

Comment: just use the selection changed event, get all the items in the combo box, and remove those that are selected

Answer (score -1):

```
Dictionary<string, string>test = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        test.Add("1", "dfdfdf");
        test.Add("2", "dfdfdf");
        test.Add("3", "dfdfdf");
        comboBox1.DataSource = new BindingSource(test, null);
        comboBox1.DisplayMember = "Value";
        comboBox1.ValueMember = "Key";

// Get combobox selection (in handler)
string value = ((KeyValuePair<string, string>)comboBox1.SelectedItem).Value;
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question, and it removes any object attached to the list item

Comment: don't just copy and past the code rather then put the link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3063320/combobox-adding-text-and-value-to-an-item-no-binding-source