# Combobox in C# i Need to fill two value in combo box

Tags: c#, combobox

i have a problem with C# code for combo box my code is here

```
cmbProjectName.Items.Clear();
if (obds.Tables.Count > 0 && obds.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
{
    for (int iCount = 0; iCount < obds.Tables[0].Rows.Count; iCount++)
    {
        cmbProjectName.Items.Add(obds.Tables[0].Rows[iCount]["Project_Name"].ToString()); 
    }
}
```

Value Add in Combo Box but i will to add the index of this item my self for further operation on other search please suggest me...

Comment: Could you clarify your question more please? it is unclear in its current state, are you saying that combobox entries need to hold two values? if so you need an object model - Also is this winforms? wpf? asp?

Comment: You need to find index of items for future use?

Comment: Yes i need to enter index of my id which i will use in future for finding result or other

Comment: @Sayse yes its window form....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JAEP's solution using class will work. Binding to a dictionary is another way, here you don't have to create extra class. [Source SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3063320/combobox-adding-text-and-value-to-an-item-no-binding-source)

The code will be like below in your case. Replace iCount with the index you want.

```
cmbProjectName.Items.Clear();
Dictionary<int, string> projectsDictionary = new Dictionary<int, string>();
if (obds.Tables.Count > 0 && obds.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
{
    for (int iCount = 0; iCount < obds.Tables[0].Rows.Count; iCount++)
    {
        projectsDictionary.Add(iCount, obds.Tables[0].Rows[iCount]["Project_Name"].ToString());
    }
}   
cmbProjectName.DataSource = new BindingSource(projectsDictionary, null);
cmbProjectName.DisplayMember = "Value";
cmbProjectName.ValueMember = "Key";
```

Code to retrieve key or value.

```
string value = ((KeyValuePair<int, string>)cmbProjectName.SelectedItem).Value;
int key =  ((KeyValuePair<int, string>)cmbProjectName.SelectedItem).Key;
```

Comment: Thanks but key value is same as selected index change value

Comment: Yes, I have used iCount as the key. You have to replace iCount with your index value in this statement `projectsDictionary.Add(iCount..`

Answer (score 0):

You can create a class

```
private class Project
{
     public int ID {get; set;}
     public string Name {get; set;}

     public Project (int _id, string _name)
     {
          ID = _id;
          Name = _name
     }
}
```

Then, you transform the method in this way

```
List<Project> listPrj = new List<Project>();

 if (obds.Tables.Count > 0 && obds.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
 {
        for (int iCount = 0; iCount < obds.Tables[0].Rows.Count; iCount++)
        {
            listPrj.Add(new Project(int.Parse(obds.Tables[0].Rows[iCount]["Project_ID"].ToString()), obds.Tables[0].Rows[iCount]["Project_Name"].ToString());
        }    
 }

cmbProjectName.DisplayMember = Name;
cmbProjectName.ValueMember = ID;
cmbProjectName.DataSource = listPrj;
```

Comment: Its not asp.net.. its desktop application

Answer (score 0):

JAEP's solution can also be applied in desktop apps. Please check this [MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listcontrol.valuemember%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) about `ValueMember`.

After you specify `DisplayMember`, `ValueMember`, and `DataSource`, you can get selected text and selected value with `ComboBo.SelectedText` and `ComboBo.SelectedValue`.

Or you simply just want the index, you can use `ComboBo.SelectedIndex`.