# how to change starting position combobox C# mysql

Tags: c#, mysql, combobox

I have a little trouble using C# combobox with MySql

So, to begin with... I have combobox and button on a form. After submitting a form, executes MySql query like :

```
"select * from db1.users where login='"+combobox.SelectedIndex+"')";
```

It works great, But.... if we submit  the first element of combobox - MySql FOREIGN KEY problem occures (= NULL and so on).

Any Ideas how to give him know, that first element from combobox isn't NULL ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stupid idea but who knows:
Mysql counts from 1, combobox from 0 did you try:

```
(selectedIndex + 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure what you want isn't `combobox.SelectedItem`?
This would be the case if "login" was a string in the SQL database.
If it's an integer, have you tried doing `combobox.SelectedIndex+1`? This could fix the problem if "login" starts at "1" in the SQL whilst SelectedIndex starts at 0 in C#.

In any case, check the answer below if your problem is the combobox having no selected item.
Optionally you can have the form OnLoad do `combobox.SelectedItem=1;`

Answer (score 0):

I'll assume you're talking about just submiting the button without actually selecting a value on the combobox, right?

You should do a simple if before executing your command, like:

```
if (combobox.SelectedIndex != null)
{
  codethis("select * from db1.users where login='"+combobox.SelectedIndex+"')");
}
else
{
  //do something else
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You would want to stop using `SelectedIndex`, because it's not meant to represent your *data*. The problem may not even be in your current situation (mismatch between 1s and 0s indexing). Consider the following:

- Another developer adds sorting to your combox. Now instead of `a,b,c` the values are `c,b,a` and the selected index of 0 will now point to `c` instead of `a` as it has used to do
- Somebody removes users in the database, so in the database you now have `b,c,d`, think about what data you will have in your combobox?

To fix this problem you should use a `value`. Each combobox should have: displayed text, corresponding value (which is hidden from user) and selected index. Using selected index (or selected item) you get the item's value which should be your `database_id`. For example see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3063421/706456) if the value is not available for your combobox type out of the box.

Bonus points:

- use parameterised queries (prevents SQL injection attacks)
- never store passwords, instead store password hashes and random salts ([read more](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/51959/why-are-salted-hashes-more-secure))