# Combo box not working windows form

Tags: c#, combobox

I"m trying to add items to my combobx but it"s not working:

```
static ArrayList bandlist = new ArrayList();

public addBand()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    bandlist[0] = "test";
    bandlist[1] = "test";
    fillComboBox();
}



public void fillComboBox()
{
    foreach (string item in bandlist)
    {
        combo.Text = item;
    }
}
```

Thank you

Comment: Look over the properties of ComboBox. You'll find one that is more appropriate.

Comment: Can you please be more specific about _not working_? You get any exception or error message?

Comment: Extending @HenkHolterman comment: `ComboBox.Text` is not the right property to *add items*.

Answer (score 1):

To add items to your combobox, you have to fill the `.Items` property (which is a collection).
See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa983551(v=vs.71).aspx

You're currently using the `Text` property:

> Setting the Text property to null or an empty string ("") sets the
>   SelectedIndex to -1. Setting the Text property to a value that is in
>   the Items collection sets the SelectedIndex to the index of that item.
>   Setting the Text property to a value that is not in the collection
>   leaves the SelectedIndex unchanged.

Answer (score 0):

You are setting the wrong property. You should set the Items Or DataSource property for entering all the values inside the control.

```
    combo.DataSource= bandlist;
```

OR

```
    foreach (var item in bandlist)
    {
      combo.Items.Add(item);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need:

```
combo.Items.Add(item);
```

Comment: Thankyou but when I do this it's empty. I"m receiving it now from an array but it's empty very strange.

Comment: Seems like I was in a hurry.
Check this out: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3063320/combobox-adding-text-and-value-to-an-item-no-binding-source)

Answer (score 0):

To add an item to the combobox you should use the `Items.Add` method.

```
combo.Items.Add(item);
```

Also, I note that you use an `ArrayList`. Unless you're using the version 1 of the framework, I'd recommand to use a generic collection such as `List<string>`.

Look at [ArrayList vs List<> in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2309694/arraylist-vs-list-in-c-sharp) to see advantages of generic collections over `ArrayList`