# Options to have combobox with DisplayMember and ValueMember

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox, .net-4.0

I am trying to make `combobox` with `DisplayMember` and `ValueMember` option
I want to discuss the available options to that

**Option 1**

using `DataTable` as `DataSource` and load it into `DisplayMember` and `ValueMember` and that option will avoid me the hardcode science data are load it from the database

This option is not applicable in my case for several reason example I have not granted the create table permission

**Option 2**

using `class` as shown in this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3063421/340277) but that has disadvantage of hardcode

**Option 3**

using `Dictionary` as below

```
Dictionary<string,>test = new Dictionary<string,>();
        test.Add("1", "example1");
        test.Add("2", "example2");
        test.Add("3", "example3");
        comboBox1.DataSource = new BindingSource(test, null);
        comboBox1.DisplayMember = "Value";
        comboBox1.ValueMember = "Key";

// Get combobox selection (in handler)
string value = ((KeyValuePair<string,>)comboBox1.SelectedItem).Value;
```

to read values back

```
DictionaryEntry deImgType = (DictionaryEntry)cmbImageType.SelectedItem;
MessageBox.Show(deImgType.Key + ": " + deImgType.Value);
```

is there any other options? and may this option avoid me the hardcode pelsae ?

Thanks

Comment: What is this hardcode that seems to scare you so much?  It always amazes me how much effort people will put into avoiding a trivial task.  Also, you do not need an external database system to create and fill a DataTable.

Comment: All the options are similar, using a data source and setting display member and value member. What's the actual problem which you are trying to solve? Avoid hard-coding what?

Comment: Option 2, you can create class objects without hard-coding anything.