# Fill a ComboBox

Tags: c#, combobox

I need fill a ComboBox (Windows Forms) where have a Text and ID values. Example: 
("Team1", 15)
("Team2", 27)
...

My code didnt work :/

```
List<Team> teams = new List<Team>();
teams = sq.loadTeams();

foreach (Team t in teams){
   Combobox.Items.Add(t.getName(), t.getId());
}
```

heeelp please

Comment: Your question doesn't have enough information for us to help you. "My code didn't work" could mean anything from a compile error, to causing a nuclear explosion at your address. Please edit your question and include full details of the problem.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ComboBox adding text and value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3063320/).

Comment: Combobox.Items.Add() does not accept two inputs!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use data-binding, best feature Windows Forms come up with ;)

```
var list = new[]
{
    new Team { Id = 1, Name = "One" },
    new Team { Id = 2, Name = "Two" },
    new Team { Id = 3, Name = "Three" }
};

combobox.ValueMember = "Id"; // Name of property to represent a Value
combobox.DisplayMember = "Name"; // Name of property to represent displayed text.

combobox.DataSource = list; // Bind all items to the control
```

Selections can be accessed by `Selected..` properties of combobox.

```
var selectedTeamId = (int)combobox.SelectedValue;
var selectedTeamName = combobox.SelectedText;

var selectedTeam = (Team)combobox.SelectedItem;
```

Notice that `SelectedValue` and `SelectedItem` return `object` type, so you need cast it to correct type before using.