# Place data retrieved from the database(sql) in Table with KEY & VALUE in c#

Tags: c#, sql, .net

Lets say that I have a database containing the following:

```
 ID      CategoryName  

  1      CategoryName1
  2      CategoryName2
  3      CategoryName3
  4      CategoryName4
  5      CategoryName5
  6      CategoryName6
  7      CategoryName7
  8      CategoryName8
  9      CategoryName9
```

I retrieve the ID & CategoryName from the database and put the CategoryName list in a ComboBox ,
I take the name of Category from ComboBox and i have to get the right ID for the selected CategoryName.

I think about retrieve the data in a List with key and value

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3063320/combobox-adding-text-and-value-to-an-item-no-binding-source#39731421

Comment: Looks like this is to do with your GUI. What GUI do you use? Windows, ASP,...?

Answer (score 0):

Use Dictionary for this, Easy to Display Key and Value Pair